# How can i return mysql error with Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have to porting a web site in laravel so in my old project i call this query:

```
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_SESSION['username']);
    $nome=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['titolo']);
    $query="insert into iscrizioni values('$username','$nome');";
    $res=mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    if($res===TRUE){
        echo 1;
    }else{
        echo mysqli_error($conn);
    }
```

But now in my Controller :

```
public function iscrizione(){
            $data=request();
            $titolo=$data['titolo'];
            $user=session('user_id');
            $newIscrizione=Iscrizione::create([
                'user'=>$user,
                'corso'=>$titolo,
            ]);
            if($newIscrizione){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 
            }
        }
```

I created some triggers in my DB with a specific sqlstate_message for each so i need to return it in my js file. How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use try catch exception handling

```
 try{
       $newIscrizione=Iscrizione::create([
                'user'=>$user,
                'corso'=>$titolo,
            ]);
    }catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $exception){

        dd($exception->getMessage());
    }
```